# brew cask upgrade does not seem to work

Tags: google-chrome, homebrew

```
~$ brew cask --version
Homebrew-Cask 1.6.6
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 1c78e; last commit 2018-06-01)
~$ 
~$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
~$ 
~$ brew cask outdated
~$ 
~$ brew cask info google-chrome
google-chrome: 67.0.3396.62
https://www.google.com/chrome/
/usr/local/Caskroom/google-chrome/66.0.3359.181 (2 files, 77.5KB)
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/master/Casks/google-chrome.rb
==> Name
Google Chrome
==> Artifacts
Google Chrome.app (App)
```

Above is the output when I was trying to upgrade google-chrome. It looks like I have Chrome version 66, but the server already has version 67. However, I was not able to upgrade it with brew cask upgrade. I'm wondering whether I have done anything wrong.

Comment: I got answer for my own question. Use `--greedy`.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>There is no `upgrade` command available for `brew cask`. The GUI apps are updates by running `Check for updates...` from within the application which is generally found in the menu.</strike>

You can force install a newer version of the cask item by running `brew cask reinstall <package>`. In case of Google Chrome, run `brew cask reinstall google-chrome`.

You can use `brew cask upgrade --greedy` to upgrade all the GUI apps to respective latest version. From `man brew-cask`:

> upgrade [--force] [--greedy] token [ token ... ]
>
> Without token arguments, upgrade all the  installed  Casks  that
>     have  newer  versions available in the tap; otherwise update the
>     tokens given in the command line. If --greedy is given then also
>     upgrade the Casks having auto_updates true or version :latest.

Comment: There is `brew cask upgrade` actually. Who wants to upgrade each app separately if it could be done with a single command? The `--greedy` seems to do the trick.